Wi-Fi connection problem whenever I boot my laptop with Ubuntu as a dual boot
Here's a step-by-step procedure depicting the problem:

I boot my laptop.
I try to access the internet but it doesn't work, unless I turn Wi-Fi off and then turn it on again.

Wi-Fi works properly in Windows.
What can be the possible causes and fixes for this problem?

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager. Read man journalctl NetworkManager service. Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

But how can i fix this?

I have suggested a way for you to see more information about your problem. Please [edit] your Question and add this information, properly formatted (with the {} button. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].
